# Rails - Saving data to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

I have a question about saving data to database. This is beginners question. I just started learning Ruby on Rails. I have a user, doctor and appointment in my database.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :appointments
has_many :doctors, :through => :appointments
end

class Doctor < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :appointments
has_many :users, :through => :appointments
end

class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :doctor
belongs_to :user
end
```

I have the following controller:

```
class AppointmentsController < ApplicationController
def create
    @appointment = Appointment.new(appointment_params)
    if @appointment.save
        flash[:success] = "Welcome!"
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def destroy
end 
end
```

How to save specific appointment to database through View? How to access that method in appointments controller from view and set parameters?

Thank you very much!

Comment: "Accessing that through view" would be horrible practice, please don't do that. I recommend reading some documentation on MVC frameworks.

Comment: I know the purpose of MVC method but I don't know what to apply that here. If I would have a form in new view, the method would be triggered after I click submit, right? In my case I need to fill all data with Javascript and then somehow save it into database. I use full calendar for appointments. So, I can get clicked date, user id and doctor id. How to save them then to database? Any help would be greatly appreciated because I have a little time left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you heard of something called **"update_attribute"**, this will allow you update specific attribute/s as you wish. Just you have to pass the parameters including the id from the view.

then in your controllers do something like this :

```
user = User.find_by_id(params(:id))
user.appointments.update_attribute(:date, params(:date))
```

Checkout [this](http://www.davidverhasselt.com/2011/06/28/5-ways-to-set-attributes-in-activerecord/) link for detailed description.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `@appointment` in your view, if you are creating the new appointment then the method is new which is in `AppointmentsController` you shoud pass an empty appointment to the view and where you have `new.html.erb` with `form_for` things and then you use create to save them.